# How to get GraphQL query in AuthorizationHandler at graphql dotnet 6?

Tags: .net, graphql, dotnet-httpclient

I am using graphql-dotnet in dotnet 6, Need to get argument from the query/mutation for authentication. In AuthorizationHandler how to extract the values from query.

This is a sample query

```
{
  formQuery {
    form(id: 1, organisationId: "string") {
      id
      name
      organisationId
    }
  }
}
```

How to parse `formId` and `organisationId` from query?

This is my implementation

```
public class ValidOrganisationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ValidOrganisationRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ValidOrganisationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        ValidOrganisationRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
        {
// How to get value from graphql query/mutation

            if (/*parsed value*/)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail();
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        // return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```